# OpenVPN access server unkown IP addresses

Tags: centos, openvpn, log-files

I am seeing random IP addresses in my OpenVPN server logs -

```
20:38:08 2019 TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET] xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:45345'
09:14:22 2019 TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:52918'

18:26:24 2019 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:43551'
18:26:55 2019 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:43551 Connection reset, restarting [-1]'
18:26:55 2019 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:43551 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting'
```

Is this anything I should be worried about or is just people scanning ports?